# Optimization of General Purpose Makefile

Tags: c++, performance, makefile, make

I wrote a makefile that would generate a simple executable from the example directory structure.

```
project/
  source/
  include/
  makefile
```

The makefile itself comes equipped with dependency tracking, and automatically generates two directories named **build** and **dependency**. Currently the makefile I made works, yet it takes anywhere from three to five seconds to build the executable on my machine. I was wondering whether my makefile source code was setup inefficiently, or am I just being impatient?

```
target    := driver.exe
compiler  := g++
ccflags   := -Wall -Werror -pedantic -pedantic-errors -O2 -std=c++17
src_dir   := source
build_dir := build
deps_dir  := dependency
ccfiles   := $(wildcard $(src_dir)/*.cc)
objects   := $(patsubst $(src_dir)/%.cc, $(build_dir)/%.o, $(ccfiles))

deps := $(patsubst $(build_dir)/%.o, $(deps_dir)/%.d, $(objects))
-include $(deps)
deps_flags = -MMD -MF $(@:$(build_dir)/%.o=$(deps_dir)/%.d)

$(target): $(objects)
    @$(compiler) -o $@ $^
    @echo "Successfully built "$@"!"

$(build_dir)/%.o: $(src_dir)/%.cc | setup
    @$(compiler) $(cflags) -o $@ -c $< $(deps_flags)
    @echo "Successfully built "$<" into "$@"!"

.PHONY: setup
setup:
    @mkdir -p $(build_dir) $(deps_dir)

.PHONY: clean
clean:
    rm -rf $(target) $(build_dir) $(deps_dir)
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! The current question title, which states your concerns about the code, is too general to be useful here. Please [edit] to the site standard, which is for the title to simply state the task accomplished by the code. Please see [How to get the best value out of Code Review: Asking Questions](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2436) for guidance on writing good question titles.

Comment: There we go! Hopefully, the edits I made now narrow down what I would like advice on! I really hope that the makefile I created is inefficient. Otherwise, this makefile just proves how old my computer is.

Comment: @FooBar You have a phony `PHONY` target (change `.PHONEY` to `.PHONY`)

Comment: Whoops, let me fix fix that typo!

Comment: @FooBar "I was wondering whether my makefile source code was setup inefficiently": I doubt that this is because of your Makefile. Of course, one way to test it would be to use `time g++ -Wall -Werror -pedantic -pedantic-errors -O2 -std=c++17 -c ...` (that is, compile the object files and link them without using Make's pattern subsitution). You should make sure to do these two steps (compile and link) separately to account for possibly writing the `.o` files to disk.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of defining your own `compiler` variable, I would override the [implicit `CXX` variable](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Implicit-Variables.html). This also goes for the implicit `CXXFLAGS` (instead of your `ccflags`).

This allows other users to easily [change the compiler used](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2969222/make-gnu-make-use-a-different-compiler) when using a different environment than you.

You might also want to remove all the leading `@` in favour of [`make -s`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35451730)

Comment: I see your point @FromTheStackAndBack. I also did the `time` test you suggested, and you were right! Turns out a I left a few applications running in the background. After shutting them down, my makefile builds my executable quickly. Now I don't know if this question was a waste, but I did learn some new things about `make`, thank you!

Comment: @FooBar I would suggest [waiting a bit longer before accepting an answer](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9457/how-long-should-you-leave-a-question-before-you-accept-an-answer). Other users may have more to add in addition to what I have written.

Comment: Good advice @FromTheStackAndBack, but do I revoke the check mark? I would like to give you an up vote, yet the site tells me that I do not have enough reputation points to do so.